# $C_c^{\infty}(G) \rightarrow \textrm{c-Ind}_H^G(\delta_H)$ is surjective

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a unimodular topological group of totally disconnected type, and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$.  Let $\delta_H$ be the modular character of $H$, and let $dh$ be a right Haar measure on $H$.  Let $C_c^{\infty}(G)$ be the space of locally constant complex valued functions of compact support, and let $\textrm{c-Ind}_H^G(\delta_H)$ be the space of functions $F: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the following properties:

1 .  There exists an open compact subgroup $K$ (depending on $F$) such that $F(gk) = F(g)$ for all $g \in G, k \in K$.

2 .  For all $g \in G, h \in H$, we have $F(hg) = \delta_H(h)F(g)$.

3 .  There exists a compact set $\Omega \subseteq G$ (depending on $F$) such that $F(g) \neq 0$ for all $g$ outside the product set $H.\Omega$.

I'm reading Casselman's [notes](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf) on representation theory and trying to understand the proof of why normalized parabolic induction commutes with the contragredient.  My lack of understanding comes down to the following proposition:

[image]

It is easy to see that for $f \in C_c^{\infty}(G)$, $\mathcal P_{\delta}(f)$ satisfies the first two properties.  For the third, if $\Omega$ is the support of $f$, and $\mathcal P_{\delta}(f)(g) \neq 0$, then there must exist an $h \in H$ such that $f(hg) \neq 0$, so $hg \in \Omega$, hence $g \in h^{-1}\Omega \subseteq H.\Omega$.

What I'm having trouble with is seeing why $\mathcal P_{\delta}$ is surjective.  I do not see how I would go about constructing a suitable function $f \in C_c^{\infty}(G)$ which maps to a given $F \in \textrm{c-Ind}_H^G(\delta_H)$.  In general, I have a lot of trouble verifying that functions can be expressed as integrals of other functions.  I would appreciate any hint for how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $K$, you can show it for the $K$-fixed vectors in $\textrm{c-Ind}_H^G(\delta_H)$. If $f$ is $K$-fixed and has support $H\Omega K$ write $\Omega = \coprod g_iK$. Modulo $H$,$f$ takes finitely many values $f(g_{i}K)$, so for each $i$ define $r_i(g_{i}K)=f(g_{i})$, and $r_i(x)=0$ for $x \not\in g_iK$. Applying $\mathcal P_{\delta}$ to the constant function $r_i$ just returns the "same" function except it now transforms according to $\delta_H$ on the left, and also is scaled by the measure of $\{h: hg_iK \in g_iK\}$. After normalizing the $r_i$ to account for that, the sum of the $\mathcal P_{\delta}(r_i)$ should give $f$.