# Compactly supported modulo the center implies convergence over the unipotent radical

Tags: representation-theory, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a quasisplit reductive group over a $p$-adic field $F$ with center $Z$, and let $\omega: Z \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ be a quasicharacter.  Let $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a locally constant function satisfying $f(zg) = \omega(z)f(g)$ which is compactly supported modulo $Z$.  This means that there exists a compact set $\Omega$ such that $\{ g \in G : f(g) \neq 0 \}$ is contained in the product set $Z.\Omega$.

Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ with unipotent radical $U$.  I'm trying to understand why for each $g \in G$ the integral

$$\int\limits_U f(ug)du$$

is absolutely convergent.

Some information which might be relevant: since $U$ consists of unipotent matrices and $Z$ consists of diagonalizable matrices, $U$ has trivial intersection with $Z$.  Also, the product set $UZg$ is closed in $G$.  This is because $UZ$ is a closed subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f \in \textrm{c-Ind}_Z^G (\omega)$, so [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538308/c-c-inftyg-rightarrow-textrmc-ind-hg-delta-h-is-surjective) shows that there exists $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(G)$ such that

$$f(g) = \int\limits_Z \omega(z)^{-1}\phi(zg)dz$$

Then

$$\int\limits_U f(ug)du = \int\limits_U \int\limits_Z \omega(z)^{-1}\phi(zug)dz \space du$$

which is integration over the group $U \times Z = U.Z \subseteq G$.  The support of the function $U.Z \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $x \mapsto \phi(xg)$ is $\textrm{supp}(\phi)g^{-1} \cap ZU$, which is compact, so the integral is absolutely convergent.